# Function with doctest which use Pandas doesn't work when index has a name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, doctest

I'm trying to write a doctests but I get some errors when they are executed. When I write a doctest which retrieves a `pandas.DataFrame` with `index.name`, the tests fails.

### MRE:

Notice that:

- `pandas_doctest_with_indexname` (didn't work)
- `pandas_doctest` (works)

```py
import pandas as pd


def pandas_doctest_with_indexname():
    """Function with pandas doctest.

    Returns
    -------
    pandas.DataFrame

    Example
    -------
    >>> df = pandas_doctest_with_indexname()
    >>> df.head()
       a  b
    x
    0  1  2
    1  3  4
    """

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=["a", "b"])
    df.index.name = "x"
    return df


def pandas_doctest():
    """Function with pandas doctest.

    Returns
    -------
    pandas.DataFrame

    Example
    -------
    >>> df = pandas_doctest()
    >>> df.head()
       a  b
    0  1  2
    1  3  4

    """

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=["a", "b"])
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

### Error:

```
:!python pandas_doctst_mre.py
**********************************************************************
File "pandas_doctst_mre.py", line 13, in __main__.pandas_doctest_with_indexname
Failed example:
    df.head()
Expected:
       a  b
    x
    0  1  2
    1  3  4
Got:
       a  b
    x
    0  1  2
    1  3  4
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in __main__.pandas_doctest_with_indexname
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem there was the missed spaces next to index name `x`. For some reason, the output captured by doctest fill with spaces the gap on the right to have all rows with the same width.

So, I filled the `x` row with spaces to get aligned with `b` and now it works.

```
def pandas_doctest_with_indexname():
    """Function with pandas doctest.

    Returns
    -------
    pandas.DataFrame

    Example
    -------
    >>> df = pandas_doctest_with_indexname()
    >>> df.head()
       a  b
    x      
    0  1  2
    1  3  4
    """

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=["a", "b"])
    df.index.name = "x"
    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```